# How do you set the column's format code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I know how to set the format code for a cell, but is there a way to set the format for the entire column?

Setting for a cell:
`self.sh.cell(row=row,column=3).style.number_format.format_code = 'm/d/yyyy'`

Comment: Have you tried using a for loop?  Also see the [worksheet.range](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/api.html#module-openpyxl-worksheet-worksheet) function.

Comment: Currently that's what I'm doing.  For a unknown reason the formatting in various cells change after accessing the cells' value.  I can't figure out why, so for now I'm formatting every cell after every change.  I thought if you could set the column's format code like you can in excel it would at least be cleaner.

Comment: I browsed the [openpyxl docs](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/api.html) for a bit, and I don't see any way to do it other than iterating over a list of cells.  And without more code, I couldn't say why the number formats are changing when you access the cells.